# Package 'g++-4.8' has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, compiling, gcc, 20.04, g++

So i recently updated to Ubuntu-20.04 and my g++-4.8 compiler got deleted
when i tried to reinstall it using "sudo apt-get install g++-4.8" i get an error:

"Package g++-4.8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'g++-4.8' has no installation candidate"

Im kinda new to linux so any help is appreciated
thank you.

Comment: `20.04` does not have `g++-4.8`. Can't you just use [g++-9](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/g++-9) ?

Comment: No. the college i study in uses g++-4.8 on its systems don't ask why so i have to use the same version for doing homework

Comment: Add a temporary line to /etc/apt/sources.list : `deb [URL] bionic main universe` ... and update package list `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install g++-4.8`

Comment: @KnudLarsen That worked you're amazing thanks